# Checking permission for editing entries from inside template

Tags: permissions

How do I check permission for editing entries belonging to a specific section?

When I try `{{currentUser.can('editEntries:'~entry.sectionId) }}`, it returns false - and I am sure that `currentUser` can edit entries from this section.

edit:
Its craft 3.1

Comment: Is this Craft 2 or 3?

Comment: @BradBell Its craft 3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Craft 3.1, permissions checks are done based on `uid` now, not `id`.

This should work:

```
{{ currentUser.can('editEntries:'~entry.getSection().uid) }}
```